# Evaluating general term of a $a_{n+1} = pa_n + f(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Similar to how we find out the general term of $a_{n+1} = pa_n + q$ how can I find the general term of $a_{n+1} = pa_n + f(n)$ without use of characteristic equation? I'm pretty sure I saw an article about it on some language I could not understand.

*Note, that I am not aware of how characteristic equation works and only heard of it.*

Comment: There is no general formula with a generic $f(n)$. However, there is a standard way of proceding. First of all, you have to find a specific solution to the recurrence, and you need to guess it based on the type of function of $f$ (for example, if $f$ is a polynomial, try a polynomial). Then, if $b_n$ is your special solution, consider the sequence $c_n=a_n-b_n$ and try to figure out the type of recurrence it satisfies.

Comment: in the article i found it has the following image(not a mathematical one)

$a_{n+1} = pa_n + f(n) \implies a_{n+1} + \alpha (n+1) + \beta = p(a_n + \alpha + \beta)$ maybe is this what you are talking about?

Comment: I am not sure of how that formula is right, if $f$ can be any function then it is not always true. Try not to find solutions for a generic $f$ but try to solve it with particular functions that "behave well"

Comment: when we assume it is a polynomial will it work? i am also not sure and in fact have no idea how this works

Comment: It depends on the polynomial, its degree, its coefficient. Recurrence relation are very hard and only rarely have "nice" solutions, and I think the one you are considering is too generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us compute the first few terms of the sequence:
\begin{align}
a_1&=pa_0+f(0), \tag{1} \\
a_2&=pa_1+f(1)=p^2a_0+pf(0)+f(1), \tag{2}\\
a_3&=pa_2+f(2)=p^3a_0+p^2f(0)+pf(1)+f(2). \tag{3}
\end{align}
The pattern is now clear: the general term of the sequence is
$$
a_n=p^na_0+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p^{n-1-k}f(k). \tag{4}
$$
This formula can be formally proved by induction. It is certainly valid in the base case $n=1$:
$$
a_1=pa_0+f(0)=p^1a_0+\sum_{k=0}^0p^{0-k}f(k). \tag{5}
$$
Now, assuming that $(4)$ is valid for $n\ge 1$, we can show that it is valid for $n+1$:
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}=pa_n+f(n)&=p\left(p^na_0+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p^{n-1-k}f(k)\right)+f(n) \\
&=p^{n+1}a_0+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}p^{n-k}f(k)+p^{n-n}f(n) \\
&=p^{n+1}a_0+\sum_{k=0}^{n}p^{n-k}f(k). \quad\square\tag{6}
\end{align}